# Spring Data jpa with transaction management using multiple tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Override
@Transactional
public AgentRegistrationWrapper register(Argument1 arg,Argument2 arg2) {
     addressProofService.save(addressProofInformation);
     contactService.save(contactInformation);
     int i = 1 /0; //Force fully send arithmatic Exception
     panCardService.save(panCardInformation);
}
@Transactional
public ContactInformation save(ContactInformation information) {

    ContactInformation contactInformation = contactRepository.save(information);
    return contactInformation;
}
@Override
@Transactional
public PANCardInformation save(PANCardInformation information)  {

    String fileName=fileUpalodService.uploadAddressProof(information.getPanCopyFile());
    if(fileName != null)
        information.setPanDocumentProof(fileName);
    return reposetory.save(information);
}
@Override
@Transactional
public DepositInformation save(DepositInformation depositInformation) {
    return reposetory.save(depositInformation);
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<AgentRegistrationWrapper> registerAgent(
        @RequestParam(value="pan_scan_copy",required=false) MultipartFile panCopy,
        @RequestParam("agentInformation") String agentRegistrationStr,
        @RequestParam(value="address_proof",required=false) MultipartFile addressCopy,
        @RequestParam(value="nope_proof",required=false) MultipartFile nopeProofCopy )
        throws Exception  {


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AgentRegistration agentRegistration = mapper.readValue(agentRegistrationStr, AgentRegistration.class);
    AgentRegistrationWrapper checkAgentData = null;



    if (validate(agentRegistration))
        checkAgentData = agentRegistrationService
                .findByEmail(agentRegistration.getContactInformation().getEmail().toString().trim());//It is checking in database data exist or not ,if not it will register
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    if (checkAgentData == null) {

        AgentRegistrationWrapper agentRegistrationWrapper2 = agentRegistrationService.register(agentRegistration,
                panCopy, addressCopy,nopeProofCopy);

        if (agentRegistrationWrapper2 == null) {
            logger.error("No data found", agentRegistrationWrapper2);
            return new ResponseEntity<AgentRegistrationWrapper>(agentRegistrationWrapper2, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            logger.debug("Inside the error");
            agentRegistrationWrapper2.getAgentRegistrations().getPanCardInformation().setPanCopyFile(null);
            //agentRegistrationWrapper2.getAgentRegistrations().getAddressProofInformation().setAddressCopyFile(null);
            return new ResponseEntity<AgentRegistrationWrapper>(agentRegistrationWrapper2, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(checkAgentData);
        checkAgentData.getAgentRegistrations().getPanCardInformation().setPanCopyFile(null);
        return new ResponseEntity<AgentRegistrationWrapper>(checkAgentData, HttpStatus.ALREADY_REPORTED);
    }

}
```

I have four services in that register is outer services I am calling three services inside register service I am force fully throwing arithmetic exception 
but database is not rollback i have used spring data jpa repository.If any service is going fails in between other database data should be rollback.And important thing is that  I have three different table.

Comment: try to show us the method that calls register method.. with annotations if any

Comment: Resolved this problem database engine problem

Comment: Database engine was the problem.I changed my DB engine as a InoDB